# How to get 2nd part of output and graph?

Tags: java

[This shows what program I need to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpjrA.png)

This is the code I have so far and I do not know how to get the 2nd part of the output where it reads the 2nd file and outputs the meaning and how to draw the graph. Thank you in advance any tips will help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BabyNames {

    //class constants for open area in graphics (Do NOT change)
    private static final Integer OPEN_AREA_WIDTH = 780;
    private static final Integer OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT = 500;

    //prompt msg class constants (Do NOT change)
    private static final String MESSAGE_PREFIX = "This program allows you to search through the\n" +
            "data from the Social Security Administration\n" +
            "to see how popular a particular name has been\n" +
            "since ";

    // class constant for meaning file (Do NOT change)
    private static final String MEANING_FILENAME = "meanings.txt";

    // class constant for name file (Change the value only. Do NOT change the names of the constant)
    // Test with both "names.txt" and "names2.txt" (Before submission, change back to "names.txt")
    private static final String NAME_FILENAME = "names.txt";

    // Other class constants (Change the value only. Do NOT change the names of the constants)
    private static final Integer STARTING_YEAR = 1890; // change the value according to spec
    private static final Integer DECADE_WIDTH = 60; // change the value according to spec
    private static final Integer LEGEND_HEIGHT = 30; // change the value according to spec

    // YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO ADD ANY OTHER CONSTANTS THAN ABOVE

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File("meanings.txt"));
        System.out.println(MESSAGE_PREFIX + STARTING_YEAR + ".");
        String name = takeName(console);
        String gender = takeGender(console);
        String look = lookName(input1, name, gender);
        String mean = lookMean(input2, name, gender);
        graph();
    }

    public static String takeName(Scanner console) {
        System.out.print("Name:");
        String name = console.next();
        return name;
    }

    public static String takeGender(Scanner console) {
        System.out.print("Gender (M or F):");
        String gender = console.next();
        return gender;
    }

    public static String lookName(Scanner input1, String name, String gender) {
        while (input1.hasNext()) {
            String text = input1.nextLine();
            Scanner search = new Scanner(text);
            gender = gender.toUpperCase();
            if (search.next().equalsIgnoreCase(name) && (search.next().equals(gender))) {
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
        return (" not found");
    }
    public static String lookMean(Scanner input2, String name, String gender) {
        while ( input2.hasNext()) {
            String text2 = input2.nextLine();
            Scanner search = new Scanner(text2);
            gender = gender.toUpperCase();
            if (search.next().equalsIgnoreCase(name) && (search.next().equals(gender))) {
                System.out.println(text2);
            }
        }
        return (" not found");
    }
    /*public static void graph() {

        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(780, 560);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.drawLine(DECADE_WIDTH, DECADE_WIDTH - 10, DECADE_WIDTH, LEGEND_HEIGHT);
        g.drawLine(DECADE_WIDTH, LEGEND_HEIGHT, LEGEND_HEIGHT + 100, LEGEND_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 720 + OPEN_AREA_WIDTH, OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT);
        g.fillRect(0, 560 - OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT, 720 + OPEN_AREA_WIDTH, OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0, OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT, 720 + OPEN_AREA_WIDTH, OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT);
        g.drawLine(0, 560 - OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT, 720 + OPEN_AREA_WIDTH, 560 - OPEN_AREA_HEIGHT);

        }*/
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Is your program correctly printing the string for the name and the meaning?

Comment: no, I can not get meaning which is " Michelle f french, english...". My output prints a different meaning from the meanings.txt file

Comment: Are the meanings in the same order as the names, or do you need to find them?

Comment: I need to find them.

Comment: Then you can do the same thing you have successfully done to find the name.

Comment: i tried that it did not work

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you tried, and explain what happened. "It didn't work" is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry i edited it now. I think i am supposed to output the meaning of the name if the name and gender combination is found.

Comment: And what does this version output?

Comment: it outputs the first part where it says "Michelle   F  0  0  0  0  0 728  173 39 4  10 22  52 125" but not the second part which is the meaning

Comment: Your code looks the same for both your look... methods, so if the first works I'd expect the second to. Have you tried stepping through the meaning lookup with a debugger?